# In Heroku where can I get the FIXIE URL value from add ons?

Tags: heroku, cloud

Accidentally I have deleted the FIXIE_URL config variable from my Heroku dyno, Now to set it up that value , I need to know the Fixie url value, I could see an add on for Heroku but nowhere in it I could find the URL which has to be configured in Dyno settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `heroku releases` - every config change you do will be tagged as release. That will show you a list of releases, one of which will be you deleting the config var. Inspect the release prior with `heroku releases:info vXXX`, copy the config var and then manually set it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the `FIXIE_URL` from the Fixie dashboard. To do so, you can run `heroku addons:open fixie` in your shell or by clicking on your Fixie addon in the "Resources" tab of your application in the [Heroku dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps).